# Longest common subsequence (LCS) for multiple strings

Tags: python, algorithm, strings, python-3.x

How would you improve this code? Particularly the **check** and **check_all** functions?

The time complexity of the algorithm of **mlcs** is \$O(|\Sigma|MN)\$, where \$\Sigma\$ is the alphabet, M is the number of strings and N is the length of the strings.
Is that right?

My analysis: candidates() performs \$O(|\Sigma|M)\$ operations and is called \$O(N)\$ times.

Based on the reviewed code posted before at
[Multiple longest common subsequence (another algorithm)](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/90194/multiple-longest-common-subsequence-another-algorithm)

```
def check(string, seq):
    i = 0
    j = 0
    while i < len(string) and j < len(seq):
        if string[i] == seq[j]:
            j += 1
        i += 1
    return len(seq) - j

def checkall(strings, seq):
    for x in strings:
        a = check(x, seq)
        if not a == 0:
            print(x, seq, a)
            return False
    return True

def mlcs(strings):
    """Return a long common subsequence of the strings.
    """
    if not strings:
        raise ValueError("mlcs() argument is an empty sequence")
    strings = list(set(strings)) # deduplicate
    alphabet = set.intersection(*(set(s) for s in strings))

    # indexes[letter][i] is list of indexes of letter in strings[i].
    indexes = {letter:[[] for _ in strings] for letter in alphabet}
    for i, s in enumerate(strings):
        for j, letter in enumerate(s):
            if letter in alphabet:
                indexes[letter][i].append(j)

    # Generate candidate positions for next step in search.
    def candidates():
        for letter, letter_indexes in indexes.items():
            candidate = []
            for ind in letter_indexes:
                if len(ind) < 1:
                    break
                q = ind[0]
                candidate.append(q)
            else:
                yield candidate

    result = []
    while True:
        try:
            # Choose the closest candidate position, if any.
            pos = None
            for c in candidates():
                if not pos or sum(c) < sum(pos):
                    pos = c
            letter = strings[0][pos[0]]
        except TypeError:
            return ''.join(result)
        for let, letter_indexes in indexes.items():
            for k, ind in enumerate(letter_indexes):
                ind = [i for i in ind if i > pos[k]]
                letter_indexes[k] = ind
        result.append(letter)

strings = []
# Alphabet for the strings.
sigma = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
# Alphabet for the LCS.
sigmax = ["e", "f", "g"] 
import random
Nx = 67 # Length of LCS.
N = 128 # Length of strings. N >= Nx.
M = 128 # Number of strings.
x = ""
for _ in range(Nx):
    x += random.choice(sigmax)
for _ in range(M):    
    string = ""
    for _ in range(N):
        string += random.choice(sigma)
    indexes = list(range(N))
    random.shuffle(indexes)
    indexes = sorted(indexes[:len(x)])
    for j in range(len(x)):
        string = string[:indexes[j]]+x[j]+string[indexes[j]+1:]
    strings += [string]

#strings = ["abbab", "ababa", "abbba"]
#strings = ["abab", "baba", "abaa"]
#strings = ["bacda", "abcde", "decac"]
#strings = ["babbabbb", "bbbaabaa", "abbbabab", "abbababa"]
#strings = ["ab", "aba"]
#print("Strings:")
#print(strings)
l = mlcs(strings)
print("LCS:")
print(l, len(l), checkall(strings, l))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Conventions

It's highly recommended to have all `imports` at the top of your file.
It's not nice for readers to have a different environment than expected.

It's also better to be safe than sorry, so you may want to wrap your global code in a `if __name__ == '__main__':`.

One-line docstrings by convention have both `"""` on the same line.
You must be thinking of multi-line docstrings, where the last `"""` goes on a new line.

## Code

### `checkall`

Python has some strong readability conventions.
For example, in `checkall` you use the not operator after the equals operator.
This is strange, as you could just use the not equals operator.
**But** in Python `if a != 0:` is always true and false every time `if a:` is.
And so it's *better* to just use `if a`.

```
# Using two operators rather than one
if not a == 0:
    ...

# Comparing to value (twice).
if a != 0:
    ...

# What you want to be doing:
if a:
    ...
```

---

I like the idea of writing declarative statements from functional programming,
which can really help readability in `checkall`.

If we were to say what the algorithm is:
Go through the list of strings, if `any` of them after going through `check` are true return false, otherwise return true.

Which can be converted to:

```
def checkall(strings, seq):
    return not any(check(x, seq) for x in strings)
```

### `check`

A bit of a 'out there' one, even though it's harder to think backward in algorithms, or at least for me.
Changing check to run backwards can improve readability.
Rather than doing `n < len(...)` you can just do `n >= 0`.

It's not that big a difference, so you may not want to think about doing it.
But it will save a few cycles on all the `len`s.

### `mlcs`

poor variable names such as `s`, make reading a little harder, `s` is short for `string`, but could be `super`, `special` or `soup`.
It's much easier to comprehend `enumerate(string)`. In changing it it will also not be hidden in the other one letter variables.

this lead to me not quickly understanding what you are doing in the bits after `candidates`.

---

There are other problems, `candidates` can be put in the for loop, rather than as a function. And you should try to reduce the 8 for-loops that the function has.

Answer (score 1):

Concerning `check` and `checkall`, I would change function names to describe what they are checking, and iterate over the characters using `for` loops:

```
def is_subsequence(string, seq):
    string_iter = iter(string)
    for seq_char in seq:
        for string_char in string_iter:
            if seq_char == string_char:
                break
        else: # ran out of string
            return False
    return True

def is_common_subsequence(strings, seq):
    return all(is_subsequence(string, seq) for string in strings)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a strange test for not zero. Instead of this

```
if not a == 0:
```

people usually use the not equal to operator, `!=`. You could alternatively use truthiness. In Python, an integer interpreted as a boolean is `False` for 0 and `True` for any other number, so you could use either of these cases:

```
if a != 0:
if a:
```